# Getting the number of posts a user has by the number of rows returned?

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a question.
I have chatting/IM website that I am working on and I was making a user profile page. I wanted to show how many posts that user had.

Another issue I had earlier was that when I called a certain value it would return a 'Resource #1' type string. But I got that working by using

```
$totalposts=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE Username='" . $username . "'");
$totalposts = mysql_fetch_row($totalposts);
$totalposts = $totalposts[0];
```

But that just returns the last postID of the most recent post. I thought that mysql_num_rows would work. But this code returns an error (example with numbers):

```
29: $totalposts=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE Username='" . $username . "'");
30: $totalposts = mysql_num_rows($totalposts);
31: $totalposts =mysql_fetch_row($totalposts);
32: $totalposts = $totalposts[0];
```

That returns this error:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_row(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in       /home/a9091503/public_html/im/user.php on line 31
```

Thanks guys. :) I hope you can figure this out. :D

Comment: Why don't you use Count(*) in the query.

Comment: Shouldn't your num_rows be after you query the database, not before?

Comment: What in the world? You're assigning the result resource to `$totalposts`,  then you override it with the result from `num_rows`, and then you try to override it two more times after that. Of course you're getting a warning at that point, $totalposts is no longer a result resource... Perhaps you should look into variables and assignments too. :/

Comment: Take a look at http://www.w3ctutorial.com/sql-functions/sql-func-count for info on COUNT after you have fixed your $totalposts assigment issues.

Comment: @MetalFrog Yeah, that makes since. >.<

Comment: hey, dont be upon him. He is beginner. Always think before u give him -1

Comment: Thanks, @DigitalAssets. I think it's alright though. I'm not really a beginner in programming. Just on stackoverflow. :)

Comment: yep, that's what i said. no prob bro.

Comment: I sense SQL injection...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `posts` WHERE Username='$username'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
$totalposts = $row['count'];
```

Comment: Thank you. This also works. I'll probably end up using your code because I see your point.:) Did I display my question pretty easily?

Answer (score 0):

```
$posts=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE Username='" . $username . "'");
$totalposts = mysql_num_rows($posts);
print "total posts by user = ".$totalposts
```

You could you this query in case you want to display comment's or take other action based on number of comments. (this would reduce multiple queries, like one of number of rows and one for content)

If you are interested only in number of comments - then use following query as already suggested in one of the answer above.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `posts` WHERE Username='$username'
```

Comment: Thanks, man. Its pretty simple, but I guess it's always good to have a fresh set of eyes to see things I missed. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
$totalposts=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(postID) FROM `posts` WHERE Username='" . $username . "'");
```

or

```
$totalposts=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `posts` WHERE Username='" . $username . "'"); 
$result= mysql_query($totalpost);
$totalposts = mysql_result($result, 0, 0) // return first row and first col
echo $totalpost;
```